# "setOnClicklistener" not working in Android Studio 3.5

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to Android Programming and I am making a simple browser in which I want to open my web activity by clicking the button but I am amazed to see that setOnClicklistener is not available in Android Studio 3.5 as I have just updated[image]

Comment: Did you try an invalidate/restart (from the File Menu)? Also type `button.set...` because the Java method is setOnClickListener (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener))

Comment: I think R.id.google is a view and it providing you onClickListener method just see above image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the functional elements' code is to be initialized in the activity's `onCreate()` method. Since you want to make a button clickable, you need to add the `setOnClickListener()` in the `onCreate()` method, like so:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selectionactivity); 

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.google); //this id should be of a button not a view
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
            //TODO do something
       }
    }
}
```

I highlighted some text because from the image, you can see that the 9<sup>th</sup> that you get from the code completion menu is the setOnClickListener but the parent is from the group `android.view.View` but not from `android.widget.Button`. Make sure, that `R.id.google` is a Button and also put the code inside `onCreate()`

Answer (score 8):

You need to put the `setOnClickListener` in one of the activity callbacks. In your `onCreate()` method, move the button there and then `setOnClickListener()`.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.filters); 

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.google);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
            //TODO()
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Access/init Your button inside onCreate() method.

```
private Button btn;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_search_layout);

        btn = findViewById(R.id.someId);

        setClickListener();

    }

    private void setClickListener() {

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }
```